# Searchbar on firebase database

Tags: android, search, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to perform search on my book database which is stored in firebase. How can I write queries for that and also wanted to store result in list view? Anybody please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific on the search. How do you want your users to search. Firebase provides certain options but, there is no straightforward way similar to SQL databases like '%blah%' or where column1 != 'ABC'.

However, I have heard many people implemented more intricate search and filters by using Elasticsearch. Here is a good article on it. [Elasticsearch with firebase](https://medium.com/@NodeArt/improving-firebase-database-searching-abilities-with-elasticsearch-f999245e3925)